# Canopy does not run code

Tags: python, canopy

I've installed Canopy and completed the environment setup. Unfortunately, nothing I input into the code editor gets printed onto the Python interpreter pane (e.g. I input print "hello world" and hit enter but nothing happens. Also, the Run > Run File command is grayed out. My directory is set at "Keep directory synced to Editor".

What's gone wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This could be any number of problems. Canopy will only execute one script at a time (though the main script can call other scripts). Have you tried to restart the kernel with `ctrl` + `.`?

Comment: I restarted it and it works. D'oh. Thanks!

Comment: Can happen for a variety of reasons. Other times you have to restart the kernel twice in a row to stop it being grayed-out.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. I solved the problem by creating an account, requesting an academic license (as a student) and logging in on the welcome screen with my account. I am not sure whether the second step (requesting a license) is necessary but you can try. See the pic below. Run and Debugging buttons are active after signing in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I.e., I could not run any code or see anything in the Python Pane.  Try restarting the kernel.  That worked for me.

Run -> Restart kernel...

or Ctrl + .